# asp checkbox oncheckedchanged not firing that is inside a bootstrap popover

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue where the oncheckedchanged event does not fire when the checkbox is inside a bootstrap popover. The event fires up when it is not inside a popover.

I am working with a grid that has few fields and one of them is an asp:Button that is used to pop the bootstrap popover from the code behind like this.

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Actions")
        {
            var button = e.CommandSource as Button;

            UserActivityManager.ButtonClicked(User, button);

            if (button != null)
            {
                var row = (GridViewRow)button.NamingContainer;

                if (approvedUsersGrid != null)
                {
                    var user = approvedUsersGrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString();

                    approvedUserHieldField.Value = user;

                    var approvedUser = approvedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user);

                    if (approvedUser != null && approvedUser.Role == UserRoles.Guest)
                    {
                        addWaterMarkCheck.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        addWaterMarkCheck.Enabled = true;
                    }

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "approvedUserPopoverScript", "$('#" + button.ClientID + "').popover({ html: true, content: $('#aprprovedUserActionButtonDiv'), container: 'body', trigger: 'focus', placement: 'left'});", true);
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "approvedUserShowButtons", "$('#" + button.ClientID + "').popover('show');", true);
                }

            }
        }
```

As we can see in the code above, I am storing the selected row in a hidden field which is later used to perform other events such as button onclick event for the selected row. I do have other asp:Linkbuttons inside a popover which works.

Furthermore, the button inside the grid pops a popover and the it's content that is located in the aspx file.

This markup of the checkbox.

```
<td id="waterMarkTd" runat="server">
  <div class="checkbox">
   <label style="font-size: 1.5rem;">
   <asp:CheckBox CssClass="bigger-watermark-checkbox" ID="addWaterMarkCheck" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="addWaterMarkCheck_OnCheckedChanged"/>
      &nbsp; Add Watermark
      </label>
  </div>
 </td>
```

Any suggestion or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Inspect the checkbox HTML in the popover, do you even see the change event attribute?

Comment: No, I do not see the change attribute. This is what I see when I inspect the **html**.                                  
              `<input id="PageContents_addWaterMarkCheck" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PageContents$addWaterMarkCheck" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$PageContents$addWaterMarkCheck\',\'\')', 0)">` @PiyushKhanna